# How to verfiy whether my application apk is properly obfuscated or not?

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, deobfuscation

I have obfuscated my android application using Proguard on Eclipse, now I have to verify whether it has properly obfuscated all classes, methods and members or not.

Can someone please provide me some input how to do this verification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to reverse engineer your application and check whether everything is obfuscated as expected.